# Convert _NSCFString to Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to save a date in a date attribute in Core-data.

However, I am getting the error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "lasttouched"; desired type = NSDate; given type = __NSCFString; value = 2015-10-13 11:08:21.'
```

When I log the value in question to the console it gives me the following: `2015-10-13 11:08:21`

The squirelly thing about this is that I am getting it from an object where the property is an `NSDate`.

When I try to convert from String to `NSDate` using `NSDateFormatter`, it says the input is an `NSDate` not a string.

Can anyone suggest what I should do to get it the above to save correctly?

Comment: Edit your question to include the code where you are “ getting it from an object where the property is an `NSDate`”, and the code where you are putting the value into an `NSManagedObject`'s property. Also show us the declarations of those properties.

Comment: You are obviously assigning an `NSString` to something expecting an `NSDate`.

Comment: Yes.  Agreed.  The problem is how to convert the _NSCF string to a date.

Comment: Use `NSDateFormatter` to convert a date in string format to an `NSDate`. There are hundreds of examples on SO.

Comment: From question: When I try to convert from String to NSDate using NSDateFormatter, it says the input is an NSDate not a string.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who may run across this odd issue in the future...

As stated in my question but some evidently skipped over in their reading this was not an date formatter question as IOS did not allow me to  use NSDateFormatter to convert the argument into a date, saying the argument was already a date, not a string.

At the same time when I tried to save the value into a date attribute in core-date, it rejected it saying it was an _NSCF string, not a date.

In other words, IOS was giving two conflicting error messages...it's a date when I tried to treat it as a a string and a string when I tried to treat it as a date.

It turns out the problem was that the while I was getting the value from an array declared as an NSMutable Array, the function that produced it was set up to output an NSArray.  This was giving a yellow warning but not a red error.  When I changed the output of the function to an NSMutableArray, the issue of what type the date was went away and I was free to treat it as a string.  Apparently, as it was outputted as an NSArray, there was some difficulty changing it.  So this was a rare but interesting case.